# Unit Testing Insert Empty Record Should Throw Error

Tags: unit-testing, nunit, moq

I am new to unit testing and I am trying to test that a new `Employee` record should not be inserted into the database.  When I call `Context.SaveChanges()` it does not throw the error in the unit test, but when I try it out in the `Controller` it throws an error like expected.

I am guessing that the `Employee` entity isn't being added to the context in the unit test so when I call `SaveChanges()` nothing is actually being saved?  Any help would be appreciated!

Unit Test

```
[Test]
[ExpectedException(typeof(DbEntityValidationException))]
public void ShouldNotSaveEmptyEmployee()
{
    var mockSet = new Mock<DbSet<Employee>>();

    var mockContext = new Mock<SqlContext>();
    mockContext.Setup(m => m.Employees).Returns(mockSet.Object);

    var sut = new EmployeeRepository(mockContext.Object);
    sut.Save(new Employee());
}
```

Repository:

```
public void Save(Employee employee)
{
    if (employee.EmployeeId > 0)
    {
        Context.Entry(employee).State = EntityState.Modified;
    }
    else
    {
        Context.Employees.Add(employee);
    }

    Context.SaveChanges();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When running your unit test, the Context inside the EmployeeRepository is a mocked object and there for the method SaveChanges has no implementation. When intiailizing the EmployeeRepository you should give it an actual SqlContext where your constraint is checked. However the class under test here is EmployeeRepository but you seem to be testing the functionality in SqlContext. This test doesn't seem to belong here.

Comment: So if I want to test that I receive an error when `SaveChanges()` is called I just need to pass a real `SqlContext`?

Comment: Yes, that should work. But as I said, it's bad practice.

Comment: Do you have an example of a better way I can do it?

Comment: The class under test here should be the class that holds the code which throws this exception when a validation errors occurs. In EF it could be in a IValidatableObject or in an override of ValidateEntity in DbContext.

Comment: I'm sorry, could you try to pseudocode that for me?  I am new to unit tests and they still don't make a lot of sense.  Is any of the code I have correct for this test?

Comment: Everything is correct other than the class under test :) Please elaborate on how the validation is performed.

Comment: The validation fails because on the Model I have `[Required]` fields and I am trying to save an empty `Employee`.  When `Context.SaveChanges()` gets called it's supposed to throw the exception.

Comment: The class under test would be `DbEntityValidationException`.  Would I want to compare that the correct message is being called?

Comment: The class under test is the class where the functionality is implemented. You're not supposed to test the functionality of an external library and so I think this test is redundant. If you still want to test it, use SqlContext as input for your repository. Another idea could be to write a test that makes sure that the required attributes are present in the Employee class. This can be done using reflection.

Comment: When I changed the line to `var sut = new EmployeeRepository(new SqlContext());` that did fix the issue, but you think using reflection to test the required attributes would be a better way?

Comment: It's different. Checking the attribute assures us that the attribute wasn't deleted from the entity. While SqlContext tests both that and the functionality of the model which belongs to an external library.

Comment: True, I'll look at reflection.  Is that just a Nuget package I need to install?

Comment: No it is built in .net. Read about it here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173183.aspx